# multiple insert on duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, hits) VALUES ('abc', 1), ('cde', 1), ('fgh', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = VALUES (2), (6), (10)
```

The code is wrong (probably would need to put the id in the key update) but is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `VALUES` properly, it's really rather simple:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, hits) VALUES ('abc', 1), ('cde', 1), ('fgh', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = VALUES (hits)
```

**EDIT:** if you desperately need to assign hits different values in single query on duplicate key than in the insert query, try [CASE operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).

```
INSERT INTO table (id, hits) VALUES ('abc', 1), ('cde', 1), ('fgh', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = CASE VALUES(id) 
    WHEN 'abc' THEN 3
    WHEN 'cde' THEN 2
    WHEN 'fgh' THEN 28
    ELSE 11 -- this is a default value assuming you need one
    END;
```

Comment: Cypher, we need to different hits to different ids.

Comment: Yes, this will set different hits to different ids. This will set each row the value specified in first VALUES(). For example, if the first pair ('abc', 1) will hit a unique index, it will be updated to 1. If you need to increment the `hits` value, you can use `...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = hits + 1`

Comment: what if we need it to be specific value? Like the new example in my post.

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't believe you can do this directly with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause. The only thing I can think of is using `CASE` statement, for example `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = CASE VALUES(id) WHEN 'abc' THEN 1 WHEN 'cde' THEN 2 END;`. I realize that it's rather unreadable, but if you desperately need one query...

Comment: Ok, I've tried this right now and it works, I'll update the answer so it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just set hits to 2 it's easy, do:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, hits) VALUES ('abc', 1), ('cde', 1), ('fgh', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = 2;
```

If you want to update the values with different hits per id, you need to use a different way of doing things:

From the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

> You can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... UPDATE statement. In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred. This function is especially useful in multiple-row inserts. The VALUES() function is meaningful only in INSERT ... UPDATE statements and returns NULL otherwise. Example:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, hits) VALUES ('abc', 1), ('cde', 1), ('fgh', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = VALUES(hits)+1
```

Comment: I'd actually like to set it to different hits for different ids.

Comment: Thank you Johan. For ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = VALUES(hits)+1 what if we need to set the hits to a specific value per id?

Comment: Then you will need to write explicit code that does this, either in a `before update` trigger, or in a separate query.

Comment: Right, so no way to do ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = VALUES (2), (6), (10) right?

Comment: @Patric, well you can write `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits = CASE VALUES(id) WHEN 'abc' THEN 2 WHEN 'cde' THEN 6 WHEN 'fgh' THEN 10 END` But that's a rather contrived example.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table (id, hits) 
  VALUES ('abc', 1), ('cde', 2), ('fgh', 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE hits = hits + VALUES (hits) ;    --- increase by 1, 2, 3 accordingly
```

or

```
  UPDATE hits = VALUES (hits) ;           --- set to 1, 2, 3 accordingly
```

Comment: @Patrick: I don't think this is possible with the `INSERT VALUES` syntax. The `2,6,10` (of the second case, UPDATE) being unrelated to the `1,1,1` (of the first case, INSERT).